# I wanted to write discord bot in python rewrite to check content in only embeds sent in a channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The only thing I can come up with is this but it checks normal messages too

I am using discord.py rewrite version 1.6.0

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "Blah Blah"
        print ("I got  that")

client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a message has embeds, and iterate over all embeds of a message with this code:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for embed in message.embeds:
        # do something here with the embed

client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Note that an `Embed` has a very specific structure that you can find in the [Embed documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed), just in case you want to do something with the data in the embed!

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the message is an embed, whereby you can access any of its elements. Try this out:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    embeds = message.embeds
    if not embeds: #checks if message was an embed or not
        return
    else:
        embed = (message.embeds)[0]
        print(embed.title) # you can access its other elements as well
```

Instead of printing out the title of the embed, you could do something like `print(embed.description)` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the embed description or title by doing this

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for embed in message.embeds:
        if embed.title or embed.description == 'Blah Blah':
            await message.channel.send('I got that')

client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```